# OS version IF statement

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am working with windows 7 and 8.1 machines. I would like to implement a PowerShell script to detect the OS and install a program based on the result.

So far I can get the OS but I get caught in the IF statement.

```
$Win7="6.1.7601"   
$Win8="Not tested yet"  
$Version=(Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem).version  
write-host Your windows version is $version.  

if(!($version="6.1.7601"))    
{skip}  
else    
{Install file}
```

I am trying to skip this script and return to a main script if the OS is not win7 otherwise it should install the files needed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean `-eq` there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=` operator is used to set the value of something.  You need to use the `-eq` operator, which compares objects.

`if(!($version -eq "6.1.7601"))`

Comment: Thanks for that. Things run much smoother now

Comment: I'd recommend using `-ne` instead of `!(-eq)`.

Comment: I'd recommend excluding build number from comparison. I.e. check that version starts with `6.1` only.